# How to pass all the data in dataframe that extract from excel sheet to highchart?

Tags: python, django, pandas, highcharts

I have a raw data and right now I need to used the raw data to plot a highchart and pass to Django, any one can share me the basic how to plot a highchart in order to shown in HTML page? I'm very new to python, Django and Highchart, I have read through all the related material on Highchart but I still not understand and not able to start it.

From this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic I able to contract a chart, but in my case I need extract all the data and plot a chart. I try apply {% block content%} and the title all are base on my raw data name in a dataframe but I still not able to build a chart

Comment: Have you follow this instruction http://django-highcharts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?

Comment: yes , I follow, but I get this error  **Reverse for 'bar' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [0]**

Comment: please share your views and template code.

Comment: my code all same as the link you suggested , I feel want post here but not able

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message, It seems that Django is unable to determine the url named as `bar` in your `urls.py` files, I think you forgot to put a [named urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) as `bar`, so that the javascript function can get the data from BarView.

Below add an example, the project name is `questions`, and create a new app named `charts`, the project structure will be like this:

--charts

--questions

--db.sqlite3

--manage.py

1, `questions/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from charts import views as charts_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^bar$', charts_views.BarView.as_view(), name='bar'),
    url(r'^charts/', include('charts.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

2, `charts/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'charts'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),    
]
```

3, `charts/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from highcharts.views import HighChartsBarView
import random

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'charts/index.html')

class BarView(HighChartsBarView):
    categories = ['Orange', 'Bananas', 'Apples']

    @property
    def series(self):
        result = []
        for name in ('Joe', 'Jack', 'William', 'Averell'):
            data = []
            for x in range(len(self.categories)):
                data.append(random.randint(0, 10))
            result.append({'name': name, "data": data})
        return result
```

4, `charts/templates/charts/index.html`:

```
{% load staticfiles %}<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/highcharts/highcharts.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("{% url 'bar' %}", function(data) {
            $('#container').highcharts(data);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

5, run the server, and in the browser, type in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/charts/`

it will show you the charts, hope it will help you.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I can print this , now I try to call out from excel sheet all the data , thanks